# view.setOnClick() during animation not working

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation, onclicklistener

I'm new in android development and have now problem and can not understand why and solve it.
Sorry, here is my idea and hope it helps to understand my question:
I would like to develop an app for the kids. I have two car roads. On both roads drive different cars with a certain number (0-10). The cars drive from left to right with the help of animation. A question with a number is asked. The child has to click on a certain car with the number x.
Below I've imageview (`imgCarUp1`) and try to animate from left to right. During animation I want to make click-event on my image and should run some code.

`

```
    imgCarUp1 = findViewById(R.id.imgCarUp_1);
    imgCarUp1.setImageResource(vehicleUpStreetList.get(0).getResId());
    imgCarUp1.setTag(vehicleUpStreetList.get(0).getResId());

    imgNumberUp1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("setOnClickListener Tag: %s", view.getTag()));
    ...
    });

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, width - 50, 0, 0);
    Animation.AnimationListener animL = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        LogUtils.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd is stopped!");
    }
    };

    animation.setAnimationListener(animL);
    animation.setDuration(15000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(5);
    animation.setRepeatMode(1);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    imgNumberUp1.startAnimation(animation);
```

`

Aninmation is working well. But if I try to click on imageview (`imgNumberUp1`) nothing will work. But if I click on area where animation was started, `setOnClickListener` works. I should be able to make click during animation. What is here my problem? Can someone please help with code?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Tried to search in internet, without any solution yet.

Comment: To get the correct answer I think you should present your ideas with pictures or videos

Comment: thanks, have now explained above in better:)

Comment: Animations only help you see the car moving, but your car is actually still in the same place. The car has to actually move before you can click on it, you could try researching the MotionLayout to see if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Translate animation.**  Translate Animation translates the views position to the animated positions and wont actually change the views original position.

So you will need to change X and Y value to change the original position and then handle clicks wherever the animation is currently positioned

you can do .
view.animate().X().y().start()

while x and y will have the params of where you want to animate

Comment: thank you @rahim. You explained great. So I can animate cars and create onclick at imageview. I would like somethings like `animate(fromX, toX, ...)'. It would work if I set `view.setX(...)` bevor I call `view.animate(...)`. So I got `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...)`.
As solution I use now
`ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", sourceX, destX);`
This works for me very good.
Thank you for helping, right way.